# Passing char value to function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BANINST1."F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER" (pidm number) return number
as
return_field number;

cursor get_pidm is
select distinct SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM
from SATURN.SHRDGMR SHRDGMR,
     SATURN.SORLCUR SORLCUR,
     SATURN.SORLFOS SORLFOS,
     DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST
where SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PIDM = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_PIDM = SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PIDM
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_LEVL_CODE = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_LEVL_CODE
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_DEGC_CODE = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_DEGC_CODE
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_TERM_CODE = SORLCUR.SORLCUR_TERM_CODE
     and SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM = pidm
     and SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PROGRAM in ('STCC', 'CC')
     and DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_DEGREE in ('CPCC-CDS', 'CC1-CDS', 'CC2-CDS')
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_MAJR_CODE <> DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_VALUE2
     and trim(DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID) = (select spriden_id from spriden where spriden_pidm = pidm and spriden_change_ind is null);

begin
   open get_pidm;
   fetch get_pidm into return_field;
   close get_pidm;

return return_field;
end;
/
```

This is the call to the function from a where clause:

```
baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter@test(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1) is not null
```

The function accepts a number data type parameter.
The passed column RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1 is a char(12) data type that has a value such as 293858.
The following error is returned when calling the function: ORA-01722: invalid number

I have tried to pass a number value to the function in several different ways:

```
baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter@test(to_number(trim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1))) is not null
baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter@test(cast(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1 as number(8))) is not null
```

All attempts return the same error ORA-01722: invalid number

If I hard-code the D_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1 value to a number, the function call works.

```
baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter@test(293858) is not null
```

How do I pass the char value from RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1 to the function?

Comment: In the call to F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER the database is trying to perform an implicit conversion from CHAR(12) to NUMBER and finds a non-numeric character, so the conversion to NUMBER fails.

Comment: If you are stuck with `CHAR` for reasons beyond your control, you have my sympathy. Otherwise, stop using `CHAR` and switch to the standard string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the keyword:

> **such as** 293858

Are you sure that there aren't any non-numeric values in that column? With that datatype (`char`), there's always doubt. If you are storing numbers in there, why isn't it `number`?

This query should return invalid values which cause your code to break.

```
select * from d_primary_mst where not regexp_like(rad_user_def1, '^\d+$')
```

Also, if you are passing a string, why do you force the function to accept a number? Why don't you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BANINST1.F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER 
  (pidm RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1%type) 
  return SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM%type
as
  return_field SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM%type;

  cursor get_pidm is
    select distinct SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM ...
```

By the way, get rid of double quotes when creating Oracle objects; they only cause problems.

Comment: It appears that there were non-numeric values in the RAD_USER_DEF1 column. Adding this code resolved the issue.    and REGEXP_LIKE (trim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1),'^[[:digit:]]+$')

Comment: Right; that usually **is** a cause for such problems, especially when tables contain many rows so you can't see what's wrong as selecting some sample rows looks all right. OK, I'm glad you fixed it!